# I can't use cookie in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I want to keep login status with cookie in Codeigniter, but I can't set cookie in Codeigniter. This is my code in Controller. when I click submit button in the login form it call chk_login() function to check username and password in DB. After that, it go to this line **echo "You are not log in"** only.  how to use cookie in Codeigniter.

```
<?php
class Login extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
                $this->load->helper('cookie');
    }

    function index()
    {
        redirect('login/form_login');
    }

    function form_login()
    {
        $data['title'] = 'Login';
        $this->load->view('form_login_view', $data);
    }

    function goto_test()
    {
            if($this->input->cookie('login')){
               echo "You are logged in"; 
            }
            else{

                echo "You are not log in";  // It show string in this line every time. that mean cookie not set yet. how to use cookie in Codeigniter. 
            }
    }


function chk_login()
{
$this->load->model('login_model', 'login');
$this->login->username = $this->input->post('username');
$this->login->password = $this->input->post('password');

$user_login = $this->login->get_by_user_pass();

         if($user_login==null){
                $data['errors']  = 'Not found Username.<br />';
                $this->load->view('form_login_view', $data);

    }else{

        // I set directed data in cookie but I can't get this cookie in goto_test().

        $this->input->set_cookie(array(
                               'login'=>TRUE,
                'username'=>"aaa",
                'password'=>"123",
                'status'=>"user")); 


            redirect('login/goto_test');  // Go to function goto_test in this class
    }  
}

}
?>
```

I try to test with this code it show **bool(false)**.

```
$cookie = array(
          'name'   => 'test_cookie',
          'value'  => 'test',
          'domain' => '/',
          'secure' => TRUE
          );

$this->input->set_cookie($cookie); 

var_dump($this->input->cookie('name'));
```

Comment: Where do you actually set the cookie your'e trying to validate with?

Comment: I think I will try to validate form with JavaScript. How I should to do with cookie.

Comment: Where is the string "$this->input->set_cookie()" ?

Comment: The $this->input->set_cookie() is in else{ } of function chk_login().

`$this->input->set_cookie(array( 'login'=>TRUE, 'username'=>"aaa", 'password'=>"123", 'status'=>"user"));`

Comment: Try doing this: redirect('login/goto_test', 'refresh');

Comment: I try to do redirect('login/goto_test', 'refresh'); but it same response. It can't set_cookie. I'm not sure. I set  $this->load->helper('cookie'); only at constructor. May be miss some helper define but I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know that. I can't set cookie like that. I have 2 way for set cookie.

1.

```
$cookies = array(
        array(
          'name'   => 'login',
          'value'  => true,
          'domain' => '/',
          'secure' => true
    ),
        array(
          'name'   => 'username',
          'value'  => 'aaa',
          'domain' => '/',
          'secure' => true
    ),
        array(
          'name'   => 'password',
          'value'  => '123',
          'domain' => '/',
          'secure' => true
    )
);

foreach($cookie in $cookies){
        $this->input->set_cookie($cookie); 
}
```

2.

```
setcookie('login', true);
setcookie('username','aaa');
setcookie('password','123');
```

**The cookie can't set like this.**

```
$cookie = array(
          'login'   => TRUE,
          'username'  => 'aaa',
          'password' => '123'
          );

$this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
```